# Optimize shuffled array - do I need to go through the whole array?

Tags: php, performance, random

I will try to explain my issue. I'm trying to create a chessengine in PHP (just for fun :-)) The integers in the code simply returns valid moves (for simplicity - in real code it's objects and movement pattern depending on which piece it's about)

---

**I'm looking for a way to effectively search through an array.** By effectively I mean as fast as possible. Look at my comment in code below "IS it possible to break out of loop without going through all 1000 values?" I hope the comments would try to explain what I want to achieve. I'm just looking for ideas to optimize below code, not full code :-)

---

```
//This is for demonstrating
//1000 values to go through
$moves_maybe_valid = range(1,1000);
shuffle($moves_maybe_valid);

//Go through possible values
$move_checked = [];
$nr=0;
foreach($moves_maybe_valid as $mmv) {
    $move_is_valid = check_move($mmv);

    //Check if not in checked array
    if ($move_is_valid === false && !in_array($mmv, $move_checked)) {

        //Add to checked move array
        $move_checked[] = $mmv;
    }

    //IS it possible to break out of loop without 
    //going through all 1000 values?
    //When all valid moves are true I want to break here
    //but I don't know when that is.

}

//for demonstration purpose only
//numbers (5,6) that returns true are unknown until an
//an actual check is done in this function
function check_move($nr) {
    if ($nr == 5 || $nr == 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

If I say I would generate valid moves from the beginning (based on comments below)

```
$valid_moves = [5,6];
```

What would be the best way to break out from the loop?

Comment: `foreach(range(1,1000) as $nr) $moves_maybe_valid[] = $nr;` is just `$moves_maybe_valid = range(1, 1000);` lol :P

Comment: @RoboRobok .- haha. TRUE! Sorry for that :-) LOL

Comment: you mean, `break;`?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey . ofc I can use break but I want to test all valid moves first ,but I don't know which moves are valid until check_move() returns if a nr is a valid move or not.

Comment: I can't imagine how you would know there were no more valid moves if you haven't checked if the moves are valid. Why aren't you just generating valid moves in the first place?

Comment: one optimization would be that you probably don't need to check `in_array`. Unless you have duplicates in your original list, there's no way you'd add the same move more than once. in_array is expensive and goes from O(n) to O(n^2)

Comment: Haha nevermind this. I just figured it out. If I generate all valid moves first , I just remove duplicates and then loop through the valid moves! :-)  But thanks for the in_array tip @GarrGodfrey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, the maximum number of valid moves you are likely to encounter is around 100. It can go a little higher with promotions, so if you have 9 queens maybe you get up to 200. Still, 1000 is too big.

Generating your lists of valid moves should mean you don't even need to check if they are valid. But, I imagine you are generating a list of all combinations, even if they involve passing another piece, landing on a square with your own piece, or landing outside the board domain.

I'd say, do those checks in your initial generation:

- For each pawn, check the 4 possible moves and store the valid ones
- For each castle or bishop, check the 14 possible in order, starting
  at the piece position, go in the 4 directions until you hit an
  invalid space (hitting your own piece means you've gone one too far.
  Hitting opponent piece means you've hit last possible)
- For queens, same as castle or bishop, but 8 directions instead of 4
- For knights check the 8 possible moves for validity
- For king, check the 8
  possible moves for validity
- Check if either of the two castle moves
  are possible

For each move, you also need to make sure it doesn't leave you in check. That feature can probably be optimized so you look only from the king position out.

Once you go through all the pieces, maximum of 16, your list of moves should only contain valid moves.

Where things get expensive is your look-ahead. How many moves into the future do you want to simulate? How do you measure the value/risk of each move?

Then profile. You need a good sampling profiler to optimize and find your hotspots. Pay attention to expensive convenience functions like `in_array` and avoid if you can.  Loops in loops will kill performance.